# why '@' and '.' in 'heykidhellogmail.com' returns True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello i tried to make a email parser but it behaves weirdly can someone tell me why

```
def parser(wrds):
    s = set()
    for wrd in wrds:
        splited_wrd = wrd.split(' ')
        for i in range(len(splited_wrd)):
            wrds_indexed = splited_wrd[i]
            if ('@' and '.' in wrds_indexed) and (len(wrds_indexed) > 13):
                s.add(wrds_indexed)
    yield from s


x = 'heykidhello@gmail.com', 'heykidgmail.com', 'heykidhello@gmailcom','h@gmail.com'
print(list(parser(x)))
```

output:

```
['heykidgmail.com', 'heykidhello@gmail.com']                                                                                                                                            
>>>
```

can someone tell me why does heykidgmail.com is in the list when it clearly doesnt have '@'

```
>>> '@' and '.' in 'heykidgmail.com'                                                                                                                                                    
True
```

when i ran it in console why does it say True when @ is not in the word ?

Comment: Use `'@' in 'heykidgmail.com'  and  '.' in 'heykidgmail.com'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'@' and '.' in 'heykidgmail.com'
```

does not do what you think it does.

It is interpreted as

```
bool('@')  and  bool('.' in 'heykidgmail.com')
```

Or

```
True  and  bool('.' in 'heykidgmail.com')
```

Thus

```
bool('.' in 'heykidgmail.com')
```

---

You need to test both independently:

```
s = 'heykidgmail.com'
'@' in s and '.' in s
```

Comment: now i understand thank you for your help